# Geometrical interpretation ($\left| \frac{z-1}{z-i}\right| > 1$, $\arg z < \pi$)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to ask you about the example below (I have to draw a geometrical interpretation in an argand diagram).

$\left| \frac{z-1}{z-i}\right| > 1$, $\arg z < \pi$

What I did so far:

$|z-1| > |z-i|$

$|x + yi -1| > |x + yi -i|$

$\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2} > \sqrt{x^2 + (y-1)^2}$

$(x-1)^2 + y^2 > x^2 + (y-1)^2$

$x^2 - 2x + 1 +y^2 > x^2 + y^2 -2y + 1$

$- 2x + 1>-2y + 1$

$-x +y > 0$

$y > x$

And now... The question is:

How to draw it? Is it the surface over $y=x$ function? What about the $\arg z < \pi$? Does it matter in this case?

[image: Geometric interpretation]

Or:

[image: Geometric interpretation 2]

Comment: What's the range for $\operatorname{arg}z$? Is it $(-\pi, \pi]$, $[0, 2\pi)$ or something else?

Comment: @Henry W, `RegionPlot[y > x && Arg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` that was the original query. The only condition was $\arg z < \pi$.

Comment: @HenryW, what do you think about the second one? I've redefined the $\arg z$. `myArg[z_] := Mod[Arg@z, 2 Pi]
RegionPlot[y > x && myArg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: I don't know how the $\operatorname{mod}$ function in mathematica would behave for negative values, but I can tell you that $\operatorname{arg}$ is always between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Is $\arg z < \pi$ condition unnecessary? It was originally in the exercise. I thought that  $\arg z \in < 0, 2\pi)$ and then the second image should be fine?

Comment: If that is the definition you are using, the second graph would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no need to do so much computation. $|z-1| > |z-i|$ is equivalent to $z$ being further from $1$ than $i$, and hence it is clearly the open region bounded by the perpendicular bisector of the points $(1,i)$. The other condition says that it is in the open half plane above the real axis. Combine the two to get the desired region. (So you should be using dotted lines rather than solid lines by convention.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you check this img? http://i.stack.imgur.com/aeNQr.png Is it okay now?

Comment: @terry_8: Yes right!